# Tag request - [salesforce]

Tags: support, tag-creation

I have some questions about SalesForce.

I guess there aren't many followers for it yet (not even a tag)

Can I ask to have that tag created please?

[salesforce](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce)

Comment: For other new questions you can just leave a comment asking for a retag and someone with the rep level will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce has its own [Stack Exchange site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/).

You might be better off asking your questions there instead.